# How to show that if $k | n$, then $D_{2k} \leq D_{2n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I can see why geometrically this is true. I have an idea where we generate a group with $<r^{n/k}, s>$, but I'm not sure how to complete this or whether this will really work.

Comment: What  is $D_{m}$?

Comment: @martycohen: Apparently the OP uses $D_{2n}$ to denote the dihedral group of order $2n$, i.e. symmetries of the regular $n$-gon.

Comment: @hardmath: That's correct, the notation is from Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $kl=n$. The subgroup you are looking for is $r^l,r^{2l}\dots r^{lk}=e$ along with $r^ls,r^{2l}s\dots r^{kl}s=s$.

The isomorphism between this subgroup and $D_{2k}$ is just $r^{jl}\mapsto r^j$ and $r^{jl}s\mapsto r^js$